# "Survivors" in drawing without replacement; indicator variables

Tags: probability

> A bag contains *r* red balls and *w* white balls. Each time, you take on ball out of the bag at random and without replacement. You stop as soon as all the red balls have been taken out of the bag. What is the expected number of white balls remaining in the bag when you stop?

Hello all! I'm self-studying, and came across this question in Henk Tijms' book, *Probability, a Lively Introduction*. So this is an exercise meant for practicing indicator variables, and my question is about a certain choice of it.

The author's solution labels the white balls using 1 <= k <= w, and makes an indicator variable $I_k$ for each of them: 1 for remaining in the urn till the end, 0 for otherwise. Then the author claims that when considering a particular white ball, we can "discard other white balls", and so E($I_k$) = P($I_k$) = $\frac{1}{(r + 1)}$.

What wizardry is this!? This result is consistent with the probability of having $r$ red balls and only 1 white ball, then making $r$ extractions without touching the white one. But *why is this equivalent to the original situation*?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Say we line up the $r$ red ball as a queue and the position indicate the relative order of taking out of the ball. Now you insert $1$ white ball in the queue, and there are $r + 1$ positions, and only when you insert it at the end of the queue, this white ball will be remained in the bag. So you obtained the answer. You can continue to insert other white balls into the queue but that does not affect the probability of this particular white ball remain in the bag after all red balls have been extracted.

Comment: @BGM You should write that up as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @BGM If we add additional white balls **at the end of the queue**, then they really don't affect the particular white ball.

But then, how about when there are 2 white balls (and 2 red balls)? Say we want to study the probability that _w1_ survives; one plausible sequence that allows for that is (_w2_, _r_, _r_, _w1_).
Shouldn't we also consider the placement/extraction of other white balls, and its effect on w1's "survival"?

(And yes, it'd be great if you write up an answer :) )

Comment: In this thought process, the imaginary insertion order of white ball does not affect individual survival probability (actually they have no order). Only the relative position of that particular white ball with respect to the red balls matter to the survival. In other words, if we isolate the $r$ red balls with that particular white balls from the remaining $w-1$ white balls, there are $r + 1$ way to permute them and only one way allow that white ball to survive. You can freely place the other white balls into the queue and they will not affect the survival of that white balls.

Comment: @BGM It is still a bit difficult for me to imagine, but I will go with this understanding for now. Thanks!

Maybe the following brute-force method would also work? Apply the hypergeometric distribution, and find the probabilities where we choose _r_ red balls and _k_ white balls from _r_+_w_, where 1 <= k <= w? Then we can compute the expectation value of surviving white balls

Comment: Example: say $r = w = 2$. Then if the order is $(r_1, r_2, w_1)$, then $w_1$ will survive. You can insert $w_2$ into any position of this queue, and $w_1$ will still survive. In other way round - say you have a queue of all balls indicating the order, then you can freely move the other white balls in the queue except that particular white ball. and that white ball surviving status will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I_k$ is the indicator of the event that the $k$th white ball remains in the bag after all the red balls have been extracted. The insight here is that this event is determined entirely by the relative position of ball $k$ compared to the $r$ red balls; to answer whether the event occurred, you don't need to know the placement of the other white balls, or even the *number* of other white balls; or even whether there exist balls of *other* colors in the bag. It matters only whether ball $k$ is seen at the rightmost position of the combined list of $r+1$ balls (which has probability $1/(r+1)$).

You can reach the same conclusion by considering all possible placements of these $r+1$ balls among the hypothetical "extraction queue" (of length $r+w$), answering the question for a fixed placement, and then rolling up the answer; you'll discover that the answer is the same for every placement. This is the sense in which you can discard the other white balls.

A similar insight helps you solve the problem "If you shuffle a deck of cards and deal the cards one at a time until you've seen all the aces, what is the probability that the ace of spaces is seen last?" If you realize that it matters not what other cards are in the deck, or when/how other cards were dealt, you jump immediately to the answer: $\frac14$.

Comment: I lied down and thought about it for a while. It makes sense now :) Thanks!